# External filter ag-grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I'm trying to add an external filter, but first, it didn't work, and now my grid is not displayed, it stays in loading, so I'm out of filter and grid.

At the moment I'm hardcoding the data, first, I want to make sure it works so afterward I'll fetch the data from the API.

```
export class AgreementListComponent implements OnInit {
    private gridApi;
    private gridColumnApi;
    ageType = "";

    private columnDefs;
    private defaultColDef; 
    private rowData: [
    {
        title: 'Agreement 1', status: 'Status 1', type: 'Type 1', effectiveDate: 'February/28/2020', 
        expirationDate: 'February/28/2020',
        upcomingStipulations: 'Upc Stip 1', overdueStipulations: 'Over Stip 1'
    },
    {
        title: 'Agreement 2', status: 'Status 2', type: 'Type 2', effectiveDate: 'February/28/2020', 
        expirationDate: 'February/28/2020',
        upcomingStipulations: 'Upc Stip 2', overdueStipulations: 'Over Stip 2'
    }
    ];

    constructor() {
        this.columnDefs = [
            { headerName: "Agreement Title", filter: true, field: 'title' },
            { headerName: "Status", filter: 'agTextColumnFilter', field: 'status' },
            { headerName: "Agreement Type", filter: true, field: 'type' },
            { headerName: "Effective Date", filter: true, field: 'effectiveDate' },
            { headerName: "Expiration Date", filter: true, field: 'expirationDate' },
            { headerName: "Upcoming Stipulations", filter: true, field: 'upcomingStipulations' },
            { headerName: "Overdue Stipulations", filter: true, field: 'overdueStipulations' },
    ]

    this.defaultColDef = { filter: true };
    }

    onGridReady(params) {
        this.gridApi = params.api;
        this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
        this.rowData =   this.rowData
    }

    isExternalFilterPresent() {
        return this.ageType != "everyone";
    }

    externalFilterChanged(newValue) {
        console.log('externalFilterChanged')
        this.ageType = newValue;
        this.gridApi.onFilterChanged();
    }

    doesExternalFilterPass(node) {
        switch (this.ageType) {
            case "below30":
            return node.data.status = 'Status 1';
        default:
            return true;
        }
    }
    ngOnInit() {

    }

}
```

and this is my Html

```
<div>
    <button (click)="externalFilterChanged('Status 1')">Status 1</button>
</div>
<ag-grid-angular style="width: 100%; height: 400px;" class="ag-theme-balham" 
    [rowData]="rowData"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs" 
    [doesExternalFilterPass]="doesExternalFilterPass" 
    [isExternalFilterPresent]="isExternalFilterPresent"
    [animateRows]="true"
    [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
    [enableSorting]="true"
    [enableFilter]="true"
    (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

I tried to follow this [guide](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-external/) but I can't figure out why the filter didn't work before or why my grid is not displaying anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ageType should be a global variable declared outside the class.

just look at the example again:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-external/

Answer (score 0):

seems like you are not importing `ClientSideRowModelModule` module type

```
public modules: Module[] = [ClientSideRowModelModule];
```

check out this [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/HPwnZBTXwwLFokRQ)